# Cleanup of openJPA when OSGI bundle stops

Tags: jpa, osgi, persistence

I have a set of OSGi bundles that use openjpa in karaf to access a Postgres database.  During development, I need to frequently stop, update and restart the bundles.  Although there are no log messages, I am unable to connect to the services after the re-deployment cycle.  If I halt the karaf instance and restart, I am able to successfully connect to the bundles.

I "think" this is due to not cleaning up JPA resources.

So my question is **when the JPA persistence bundle stops, what cleanup needs to be done?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use blueprint jpa you should not need to do any cleanup yourself.

I think you are hitting this bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARIES-1270.
Unfortunately I was not yet able to find the cause of it. So if anyone could spare some time to look into this that would help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for posting that it was not JPA as it caused me to continue to look.  The issue was a race condition with other bundles.